# Как сохранить значение из модели в БД (rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, подскажите как сохранить полученное после расчетов значение переменной в БД. В колонке (doc.current_money ) выводится значение которое я рассчитывал по спец. формуле (считаю  количество пациентов доктора за последние 7 суток и умножаю на цену его работы за час).

Код с модели врача  (нужное значение)

```
def current_money
   doctor_hour_price.to_f*users.where("enter_date >= ?", 7.days.ago).count
end
```

Вывод списка

```
 <% @doctor.each do |doc| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= doc.doctor_first_name %></td>
    <td><%= doc.doctor_second_name %></td>
    <td><%= doc.current_money %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Переглянути', doc %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

После этого я создал миграцию, добавил поле doctor_week_money в таблицу doctors.И хочу сохранить туда значение метода current_money (данные полученные из формулы) Подскажите как такое сделать пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы решил добавлением такого кода в модель:

```
  before_save :set_current_money
  def set_current_money
      self.doctor_week_price ||= self.doctor_hour_price.to_f*self.users.where("enter_date >= ?", 7.days.ago).count
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, в контроллере, перед выводом написать:

```
@doctor.update_attribute(:doctor_week_money, @doctor.current_money)
```

А во вьюхе  выводить поле `doctor_week_money`.

Но всё это неправильно. Данное поле должно обновляться, когда меняется `doctor_hour_price`, либо добавляется User.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "в контроллере, перед выводом написать:"? Не совсем понял Вашу мысль. перед def index или как?

Comment: Перед отрисовкой вьюхи. Внутри экшена.

Comment: Так и сделал, но ошибка undefined method `current_money'

Comment: Ну а в модели то есть то есть метод `current_money`?

Comment: Да, в модели есть. Тот код, что я сверху написал

Comment: Выкладывай контроллер.